# How to create SparkSession from existing SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I have a Spark application which using Spark 2.0 new API with `SparkSession`.
I am building this application on top of the another application which is using `SparkContext`. I would like to pass `SparkContext` to my application and initialize `SparkSession` using existing `SparkContext`.

However I could not find a way how to do that. I found that `SparkSession` constructor with `SparkContext` is private so I can't initialize it in that way and builder does not offer any `setSparkContext` method. Do you think there exist some workaround?

Comment: I'm not very sure but according to my knowledge ter is no workaround

Comment: yea :( so If there is no workaround there are two options left: using SparkContext in my application or add support for sparkSession to application I am building on the top (it is spark-jobserver, I am using their branch spark-2.0-preview however they still use sparkContext)

Comment: You only need to add support for an external SparkContext to the application and access the session.sparkContext. Shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: can you explain more by what you mean "add support for an external SparkContext" I read you should use just one instance of sparkcontext

Comment: I suppose the application creates its own SparkContext. Since you only want one SparkContext (for good reasons), you need to add a parameter to the application's constructor or builder that accepts the external SparkContext that you already created using the session builder.

Comment: the problem is the application I am using (spark-jobserver) don't allow to pass my sparkContext, it creates its own

Comment: That's why you need to edit the code of spark-jobserver (the application) not to create its own. Fork it, make your modifications, and publish it (e.g., with Jitpack). As Balaji said, there is no workaround. The only alternative is to edit Spark itself, which I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138731/discussion-between-matthias-fax-and-stevesk).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently there is no way how to initialize `SparkSession` from existing `SparkContext`.

Answer (score 39):

Deriving the `SparkSession` object out of `SparkContext` or even `SparkConf` is easy. Just that you might find the API to be slightly convoluted. Here's an example (I'm using Spark `2.4` but this should work in the older `2.x` releases as well):

```
// If you already have SparkContext stored in `sc`
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()

// Another example which builds a SparkConf, SparkContext and SparkSession
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-test").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This indeed works. This is the one that should have been accepted.

Comment: val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate() instead of sc.getConf as you already have conf.

Answer (score 21):

Like in the above example you cannot create because `SparkSession`'s constructor is private
Instead you can create a `SQLContext` using the `SparkContext`, and later get the sparksession from the sqlcontext like this

```
val sqlContext=new SQLContext(sparkContext);
val spark=sqlContext.sparkSession
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When I do this in Spark 2.2, it says SQLContext is deprecated and to use SparkSession.Builder() instead

Comment: Correct. In Spark 2, SQLContext is deprecated because everything is consolidated to the SparkSession, which is why you'd just use `SparkSession.sql()` to execute your Spark SQL, `SparkSession.sparkContext` to get the context if you need it, etc. If you're looking for Hive support (previously HiveContext), you do something like `val spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport()`

Answer (score 7):

```
public JavaSparkContext getSparkContext() 
{
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                    .setAppName("appName")
                    .setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        return jsc;
}


public  SparkSession getSparkSession()
{
        sparkSession= new SparkSession(getSparkContext().sc());
        return sparkSession;
}


you can also try using builder  

public SparkSession getSparkSession()
{
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                        .setAppName("appName")
                        .setMaster("local");

       SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
                                   .builder()
                                   .config(conf)
                                  .getOrCreate();
        return sparkSession;
}
```

Comment: in your second method you don't use any spark context, in scala I can't construct SparkSession like in your  getSparkSession()

Answer (score 5):

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include details about why and how this solves OP's issue.

Comment: In PySpark this could cause `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getAll'`