# SparkContext and SparkSession : How to get the "parallelizePairs()"?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm a newbie on Spark and need to `parallelizePairs()` (working on Java).

First, I've started my driver with:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("My App")
        .config("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .getOrCreate();
```

But `spark` don't have the function I need. Just `parallelize()` thru `spark.sparkContext()`

Now I'm tempted to add

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
sparkConf.setAppName("My App");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

This way, context have the function I need but I'm very confusing here.

First, I never needed `JavaSparkContext` because I'm running using `spark-submit` and setting the master address there.

Second, why `spark.sparkContext()` is not the same of `JavaSparkContext` and how to get it using the `SparkSession`?

If I'm passing the master in command line, must I set `sparkConf.setMaster( '<master-address-again>' )`?

I already read this: [How to create SparkSession from existing SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935242/how-to-create-sparksession-from-existing-sparkcontext) and undesrtood the problem but I realy need the builder way because I need to pass the `.config("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")` to it.

Please some light here...

**EDIT**

```
    Dataset<Row> graphDatabaseTable = spark.read()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.25.103:5432/graphx")
            .option("dbtable", "public.select_graphs")
            .option("user", "postgres")
            .option("password", "admin")
            .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
            .load();        
    SQLContext graphDatabaseContext = graphDatabaseTable.sqlContext();
    graphDatabaseTable.createOrReplaceTempView("select_graphs");

    String sql = "select * from select_graphs where parameter_id = " + indexParameter;          
    Dataset<Row> graphs = graphDatabaseContext.sql(sql);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `JavaSparkContext` using existing `SparkContext`:

```
JavaSparkContext context = JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
```

> why spark.sparkContext() is not the same of JavaSparkContext and how to get it using the SparkSession

In short, because Scala is much richer language than Java and `JavaSparkContext` is a convenience wrapper, designed to get around some Java limitations. At the same time RDD API is moved aside.

> If I'm passing the master in command line, must I set sparkConf.setMaster( '' )

No. Precedence is:

- configuration files
- spark-submit options
- `SparkConf` and `SparkContext` options.

> but I realy need the builder way because I need to pass the .config("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") to it.

It doesn't look right. `driver` option is used by `DataFrameWriter` and `DataFrameReader`. It should be passed there.

Comment: Very detailed. Thanks. I like answers like this.

Comment: About the `driver` option : Yes, I made a mistake. See my edit and please give me your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
sparkContext = SparkSession.sparkContext();

SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("My App")
    .config("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
    .getOrCreate(); 
sparkContext = spark.sparkContext;
```